# Action Script3. How to add event listener for double click keyboard's key

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, keyboard, addeventlistener, double-click

I'm creating flash game and I want to make something like:
If key "x" clicked It starts attack1 animation, If key "x" double clicked It starts attack2 animation. How to make that? I don't have ideas.

For now I have simple code, when "x" clicked It starts to play attack1 animation:

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, key_down);


private function key_down(event:KeyboardEvent)
{
    if (event.keyCode == 88)
    {
        if (attack > 0)
        {
            return;
        }// don't interrupt other attack
        for (c in codes)
        {
            if (codes[c] == event.keyCode)
            {
                attack = c;
                Hero.gotoAndStop("attack" + attack);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the time of the keypress (e.g. with `getTimer()`) and then compare the time of a secondary press to the previous time. If the gap is small enough, it's a double press.

Rough untested code to give you the idea:

```
var keysPressed:Object = {};

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyboard);

function keyboard(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if(keysPressed[e.keyCode] !== undefined)
    {
        // Compare time, maybe half a second (500ms).
        if(getTimer() - 500 < keysPressed[e.keyCode])
        {
            // Double press.
            //
        }
    }

    keysPressed[e.keyCode] = getTimer();
}
```

Comment: Add `else // single press` branch for clarification please.

Comment: @Vesper Actually for a single press you would need to do a little more work than that, a simple `else` block in there would mean the first key press wasn't counted.

Comment: Single press is in fact implemented via `return` statement under double press and single press logic following last statement in the function right now. While yes, single press logic should account for the possibility of double press after a single press event.

Comment: @Vesper Sorry, was trying to provide a simple, concise answer and thought adding everything else around that would make it hard to follow.

Answer (score 0):

```
//function for calculating is click is double click or single click:


stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkDoubleClick);
var mClick:Boolean = false;
var timer;
var timer2;
//
function checkDoubleClick(e:*)
{
    if (! mClick)
    {
        timer = getTimer() / 1000;
        mClick = true;
    }
    else
    {
        timer2 = getTimer() / 1000;
    }
    //if it is a double click
    if ((timer2-timer)<.20)
    {
        trace("double click");
    }
    else
    {
        timer = getTimer() / 1000;
        trace("single click");
    }
}
```